# How to include margins of child elements in a parent with overflow scroll?

Tags: html, css

I have a container with a set width so its children overflow and force you to scroll. Each child element (`.box`) has a `margin-right: 10px`. The margin shows until it gets to the last element at which point it is cut off at the far right edge of the element, excluding the margin.  I would like for it to show the margin for the last element, but am unable to figure out how to make this work without adding unnecessary divs to get the spacing working right, which seems like a messy solution.

*The orange area should be included inside the container (red outline)*

[image: The orange area should be included inside the container (red outline)]

**Editable codepen here: https://codepen.io/starkana/pen/wvMjdjY**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 170px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 0px;
}
.box {
  background: gray;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you could just adjust the margin? `margin: 0 1%;`

Comment: width: 150px; overflow-x: scroll; ?

Comment: @VXp to set an `overflow-x` won't work as well

Comment: @Gad Ofc it works. The point is to sum up the widths and margins and that's it.

Comment: margin does not take any space, the element does not get bigger. so that means that the margin will not work in your overflow box, padding does. The best thing you could do is to make a inner div and set padding for that div. (parent with scroll -> inner div -> childs).

Answer (score 2):

## Idea #1

The simplest thing I thought of when looking at your problem was to create another div to contain the "scrollable content". This way there is always space around the scroll section so this way it looks like it didn't get cut off.

I created a JSFiddle here, [Idea #1](https://jsfiddle.net/1L8owqzb/)

## Code

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 170px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 5px;
}
.scrollSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 170px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 1px;
}
.box {
  background: gray;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  /* padding-right: 10px !important; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="scrollSection">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

## Idea #2

I another way of getting around this I came across this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahool/62Mvn/8/)

I made a version of this idea so that it could work in your use case scenario:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 170px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 5px;
}
.scrollSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 170px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 1px;
}
.margin-end {
  background: blue;
  width: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 0px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.box {
  background: gray;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  /* padding-right: 10px !important; */
}
.container:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  background: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="margin-end">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

I also created a JSFiddle for this as well, [Idea #2](https://jsfiddle.net/BrandonCratty/1L8owqzb/10/)

Comment: the second idea is pretty trick but the first doesn't work

Comment: The first idea works in the sense that, yes the margin is not included in the scroll but by adding padding to the containing div, it would mirror what 10px would look like to the right of the last element.